# Problem in Group theory about normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ with index $n$. Prove that if $g \in G$ then $g^n\in H$. Find an example pointing that this can not occur if $H$ is not normal.

Comment: Please have a go at the question and explain what you have tried and what your thinking is. What have you tried to do to solve this?

Comment: 1st: Are you familiar with quotien groups? Lagrange? 2nd: What is the smallest group $G$ such that it has a non-normal subgroup? This happens there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for any group $G$ with $n=|G|$, $g^n=e$ where $e$ is the identity element.  So, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with $[G:H]=n$, then $|G/H|=n$.
Let $g\in G$, then $H=eH=(gH)^n=g^nH$.  Hence, $g^n\in H$.